# Percentage of Matrix Child Row Group

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to get the percentage value of a child row group value as measured against the parent row group, within a column group. However, it is giving me the percentage value of that child row group against the total of all column groups.

Essentially it seems like I need to have a hierarchy of scopes within my expression.

My report structure is pictured below:

[image]

As you can see above I have Row Groups, AgeGrouping (Parent) and Ethnicity (Child), and Column Group MemberSegmentation. The expression to create the percentage of the whole of AgeGrouping against the Column group works fine, but when I try to get to the percentage group of the ChildRow against the Column Group things break down.

The current formula I am using is as follows: countdistinct(Fields!PersonKey.value) / countdistinct(Fields!PersonKey.value, "AgeGrouping").

The output of which is pictured below:

[image]

The "Unknown" percentage value highlights the issue I'm running into, 45% is the value divided by the sum of the column groups ( 1634 / 3613 ), but I need it to be the value divided by the column group that is in the scope of (1634/2686).

Is there some expression that can get me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula/expression you need is:

=countdistinct(Fields!PersonKey.value) / (ReportItems!Textbox14.Value)

ReportItems!Textbox14.Value is the name value from the Text Box Properties relating to the totals.